# HTACCESS - REDIRECT

Tags: .htaccess

I have a few old files: homepage.html and home.html which I am sure that people bookmarked them. so I want to redirect them to the parent url. I have looked through google but they seem not to meet what i expect.

for example www.nicetomeetyou.com/home.html and www.nicetomeetyou.com/homepage.html => these files don't exist.

I want them to be redirected to http://www.nicetomeetyou

How do I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .htaccess file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^homepage.html$ index.html
RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.html
```

Comment: mod_rewrite is a very powerful tool with pretty complicated syntax … it isn't the right tool for a simple redirect of a couple of static files.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use RedirectPermanent in your .htaccess file which will let you target only specific files and let the client know that the redirect is permanent.  If you have a number of files you can use a regular expression to redirect all of them in one line.

See [here](http://www.gnc-web-creations.com/301-redirect.htm) for details or the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent).

Here is an example:

```
RedirectPermanent /home.html http://example.com/
```

Comment: I'm trying to redirect everything in a subdirectory.  I tried a regular expression, but it didn't work: Redirect permanent /subdir/*.* http://google.com